# how to get value of user id on firebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my database:

[image]

I want to retrieve user id from firebase database. How can I do that?

my code is  :

///////////// Recycler Firebase /////////////

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
        Post.class,
        R.layout.post_row,
        PostViewHolder.class,
        dbpostShow
) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

        String listPostKey = getRef(position).getKey();



        viewHolder.setTextPost(model.getText_post());
        viewHolder.setHospitalName(model.getHospital_name());
        viewHolder.setFullNameUserPoster(model.getPoster_name());
        viewHolder.setAgeUserPoster(model.getPoster_age());

        String lastSeenAgo = GetTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(model.getTime_post_ago(), getContext());
        viewHolder.setTimePostAgo(lastSeenAgo);

        viewHolder.setTypeBloodneedPoster(model.getPoster_type_blood());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), model.getPoster_type_blood(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};


recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: show your Post Class and how you are saving the userId to Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created the variable `userId` in `Post` class and use getter to get the value.

Otherwise you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to get the value:

here is the example how to use it.

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
                Post.class,
                R.layout.post_row,
                PostViewHolder.class,
                dbpostShow
        ) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

                String listPostKey = getRef(position).getKey();



                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post").child("country").child("city").child(listPostKey).child("userId");

                        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                String userID = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks you i choose this code it is working thanks you very much brother

Answer (score 0):

**you cant track value when your user id is added on the following code below , and make sure your parent position is correct**

```
yourRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        })
```